# how to use opencv graphcut

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to get a graphcut to cut out an eye in a given image and replace it with another eye.

```
void imageStitching::findEye(cv::Mat originalImage, cv::Mat eye)
{
    // our corners are just at (0,0)
    cv::Point corner1;
    corner1.x = 0;
    corner1.y = 0;

    cv::Point corner2;
    corner2.x = 0;
    corner2.y = 0;

    std::vector<cv::Point> corners;

    corners.push_back(corner1);
    corners.push_back(corner2);

    std::vector<cv::Mat> masks;

    std::vector<cv::Mat> sources;

    sources.push_back(originalImage);
    sources.push_back(eye);

    cv::detail::GraphCutSeamFinder *seam_finder = new cv::detail::GraphCutSeamFinder();
    seam_finder->find(sources, corners, masks);

    printf("%lu\n", masks.size());
    for(int i = 0; i < masks.size(); i++)
    {
        std::cout << "MASK = "<< std::endl << " "  << masks.at(i) << std::endl << std::endl;
    }
}
```

But the code crashes on

```
seam_finder->find(sources, corners, masks);
```

with the message:

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x0)
```

How do I use opencv to get a graphcut of an object at a location in an image?